# Does this integral converge? If so, then how to evaluate it?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I encountered the following integral when I was practicing some problems. Here it is :
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x} dx$$ I have absolutely no idea on how to proceed with this integral. I tried taking the absolute value of the integral and then comparing this integral with some related integrals like:
$$\left\vert \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x} dx\right\vert \leq \int_0^1 \left\vert \frac{x^n}{1+x}\right\vert dx$$ But since we are integrating between $0$ and $1$, the $1+x$ has to be greater than $1$ and thus can be removed and so I came up with this:
$$\int_0^1 \left\vert\frac{x^n}{1+x}\right\vert dx \leq \underbrace{\int_0^1 x^n dx}_{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$ And so our argument thus becomes :
$$\left\vert \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x} dx\right\vert \leq \int_0^1 \left\vert \frac{x^n}{1+x}\right\vert dx \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$$ This is all I did and don't know how to proceed further

Any help/hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since, for each $x\in[0,1]$, $\frac{x^n}{1+x}\geqslant0$, what is the point of taking the absolute value?

Comment: Of course it does converge. You proved this yourself. It is rather impossible to find a closed form for this definite integral.

Comment: Is $n$ necessarily natural? might long division work?

Comment: Please try to solve the problem explicitly in some "simple examples" first. For instance, if $n$ is odd, let's say $n=5$, we may want to write $$x^5=x^5+1-1=(x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)-1$$ and use this last form instead of the numerator in the fraction under the integral. Integration is easy and we get some "harmonic" number minus $\log 2$. If $n$ is even, say $n=4$, then write $$x^4 = (x^4-1)+1\ .$$

Comment: Almost looks like an Euler integral, too bad the bottom exponent is of this form :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

I am going to assume that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in this answer.

If $n$ is odd, then
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x} dx&=\int_0^1\frac{x^n+x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-x^{n-3}+\cdots+x+1-1}{x+1}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+\cdots-x+1-\frac{1}{x+1}dx\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{n}x^n-\frac{1}{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots-\frac{1}{2}x^2+x-\ln(1+x)\right]_0^1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}-\ln2.
\end{align}$$
Incidentally, since the integrand is always positive in the interval $[0,1]$ this demonstrates rather nicely that $$\ln 2<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$ for any odd positive integer $n$.

Can you cover the case when $n$ is even on your own now?

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :-)

Comment: Perfect answer. it's so beautiful to see how it is related to the alternating harmonic series. Thanks :) And yes, I did the even part myself

And also, if we take the limit of the sum that is, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} - \ln(2)\right)$$ then it equals $0$, right?

Comment: @Algebrology Thanks! You're welcome, I'm very happy that you found it helpful. Yes, that's right! I also very much liked its relation to the alternating harmonic series :)

Comment: Thanks again :)

Comment: can you provide your thought process(in short) while you were computing this integral? I would like to know how such a thing came to your mind. Thanks :)

Comment: @Algebrology Sure! I already knew that $$\frac{a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0}{b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0}$$ where $n\geqslant m$ can be written as a polynomial plus another polynomial over $b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0$, where this new polynomial in the numerator will have a smaller degree than the polynomial in the denominator. For example, $\frac{x^3}{x^2+2}=x-\frac{2x}{x^2+2}$. Since polynomials are very easy to integrate, I thought that rewriting our fraction in this way would be worthwhile....(continued below)

Comment: @Algebrology (continued)... A way we can do it is through long division, but I've always preferred to get rid of terms one by one which have the highest powers as I've demonstrated above. What I mean by this is, if eg we had $\frac{x^4}{x^2+2}$ then I'd first write this as $\frac{x^4+2x^2-2x^2}{x^2+2}=x^2-\frac{2x^2}{x^2+2}$, and then I'd rewrite this as $x^2-\frac{2x^2+4-4}{x^2+2}=x^2-2+\frac{4}{x^2+2}$. Of course, with practice you can skip these intermediary steps and do it all in one go as I've done in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I appreciate the time you gave to this :)

Comment: @Algebrology No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not an answer. Maybe I'm completely off here, but it does look like
$$ \int _0 ^1 x^{a-1}(1+x)^{b-1}dx =: B(a,b) $$
provided $Re(a),Re(b)>0$. So for small $\alpha>0$ we would have this written as $$\int _0^1 x^{(n+1)-1}(1+x)^{\alpha-1} dx = B(n+1,\alpha) $$
But I have no idea how this behaves as $\alpha\to 0$.